# How to upload files to ~siteurl/_catalogs/theme folder?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, csom, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

I got sucked in my project where I have upload some files at location ~siteurl/_catalogs/theme by using client site scripting like JS/JQuery/REST/CSOM ?
I searched a lot but no luck. Please help me.
It's on-premise 2016 server. We are building this solution as third party user is managing our servers and we cannot place these file directly by server access. Also,uploading a files from browser is a option but want to do this by script as there are 1000+ site collection. And manual process is not possible. At least should I am able to upload the files using client script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use CSOM. If it will run on the server, then just add reference to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Clinet.Runtime`. If it will run on some client computer, then install [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585ons/236863/how-to-upload-files-to-siteurl-catalogs-theme-folder) and add the same references.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace StackExchange.ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ClientContext cc = new ClientContext("https://sharepoint.domain.com"))
            {
                // Load only ServerRelativeUrl
                cc.Load(cc.Web, x => x.ServerRelativeUrl);
                cc.ExecuteQuery();

                // Get list by url
                List list = cc.Web.GetList(cc.Web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/_catalogs/theme");

                // Create file the library
                File file = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(new FileCreationInformation()
                {
                    // You can also add content through Stream using ContentStream
                    Content = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 },
                    Url = "file-name.txt"
                });

                cc.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```